# Android Studio's project gradle file changed?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-platform, google-play-services

I just updated Android Studio and started a new project. But now the project grade file seems different.

Here are the lines:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}
 
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now, for example, I need to paste the Firebase lines in the project level Gradle file. Where should I do it?

Here's the Firebase code:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

  }
}
```

In all of my previous projects, the Gradle structure was also like that. Now I'm a little confused about what to do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> But now the project grade file seems different.

Yes, starting with the new [Bumblebee](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/01/android-studio-bumblebee-202111-stable.html) update of Android Studio, the build.gradle (Project) file is changed. In order to be able to use Google Services, you have to add to your build.gradle (Project) file the following lines:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.0' apply false 
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And inside your build.gradle (Module) file, the following plugin IDs:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' 
}
```

In this way, your Firebase services will finally work.

P.S. Not 100% sure if the [Firebase Assistant](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) is updated with these new Android Studio changes.

**Edit 2022-14-07**:

Here is a repo that uses this new structure:

- https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp

**Edit:**

There is nothing changed regarding the way you add dependencies in the build.gradle (Module) file. If for example, you want to add Firestore and Glide, please use:

```
dependencies {
    //Regular dependecies
    implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4")
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0"
}
```

**Edit2:**

With the new updates, you don't need to worry about adding any lines under the repositories { }. That was a requirement in the previous versions.

Comment: Thank you so much. Also for for example for glide I need to add   mavenCentral() inside repositories { } on project gradle file. Where should I add it on the updated structure?

Comment: For using Firebase and Glide, for example, please check my updated answer. Does it work now?

Comment: Dependencies { } is still the same as the previous versions... So no confusions there. But for some libraries we used to add a specific repository line in the project gradle file. ( Example : https://imgur.com/a/j1sbxBB ). So we don't have to add them anymore on the newer file?

Comment: No, there is no need for that. Give it a try and tell me if it works with both Firebase and Glide, ok?

Comment: Thanks for confirming. And yes I tried and it works just fine.

Comment: You can also mention about not needing to worry about adding any lines under the repositories { } on the updated project gradle file in your answer. It's mentioned in so many libraries as a requirement. So some people may get confused.

Comment: Good point. Just updated my answer.

Comment: Sir, how do I know id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version is 4.3.0 or 4.3.x sth else?

Comment: @Raii It's present in the `plugins` part and it's `'4.3.0'`.

Comment: Is there a documentation about this changed? What is apply false means and does all `:` will just be replaced with dot `.`. Based on your sample from `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` to `id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false`

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS Yes, that's the replacement.

Comment: @AlexMamo why can't one use the version 4.3.10?

Comment: Also, how should one add the perf, crashlytics dependencies?

Comment: @JosephWambura You should add them in the same way I have added Firestore. If you have a hard time, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, so I or other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Is there an explanation why for the project level dependency you need to specify version 4.3.0, and not 4.3.10 as in the question, or 4.3.12 as Firebase is recommending to me now?

Comment: @InvisibleGorilla This answer is 6 months old. So you should use the latest versions.

Comment: @AlexMamo I tried using the latest version numbers but it does not work in this new gradle file structure. It throws an UnknownPluginException.  `Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo`

Answer (score 2):

For whoever encounter this issue after `Flutter v3.10.6`

1. Inside `build.gradle` (project) update `minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion` to `minSdkVersion 21`.
2. Inside `build.gradle` (module) update `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'`

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem just add in the gradle.build project

> id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.0' apply false

and then add in gradle.build module

> dependencies {
> //Regular dependecies
> implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.0")
> implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore"

}

Answer (score 0):

You will find your classpath from https://console.firebase.google.com/

**You will find something like this in the firebase**(if you already got your **classpath** then you can ignore this section)

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
  dependencies {
    ...
    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

  }
}

allprojects {
  ...
  repositories {
    // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

  }
}
```

***just copy the classpath***

**1)In build.gradle(project)**
**before plugins make these changes-->**

```
         buildscript {

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**2)In build.gradle(module) add these lines in pulgins and dependencies section**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

} 
dependencies {
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.2.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```