# Android Studio - Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config

Tags: firebase, android-studio, gradle

I wish to develop a chat app using firebase. However, I can't Connect to Firebase in the assistant pannel. Instead, it shows this error message

`Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.`

I tried searching up for fix online people suggest to delete `jCenter()` from gradle but i don't even have this code in my file. I was able to sync my project everything seems to work fine except i couldn't connect to it.

Project gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin:secrets-gradle-plugin:2.0.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "android.exercise.myExercise"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        Properties properties = new Properties()

        properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
        manifestPlaceholders = [MAPS_API_KEY: "${properties.getProperty('secret-apiKey')}"]
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.github.VishnuSivadasVS:Advanced-HttpURLConnection:1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // chat sys
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

}
```

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed) can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but I can still help. I had the same problem. And I solved the problem

File>Project Specture>Modules
or
Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S >Modules

Compile sdk Version: 32 or latest version
Build Tools Version: 32.0.0 or latest version

then click Apply button
then click OK button

and the problem will be solved.

Sorry for my english, i don't know english.

Answer (score 0):

##### Add MAVEN in Project gradle:

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // Add this repository
    }
```