# Getting 'Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.' error in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting the above error in Android Studio while trying to connect with Firebase. My Android Studio is currently in its latest version (bumblebee). The exact same file seemed to work fine in my colleagues laptop. Here's what my grade build (app) looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.firebasecrudapp"
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Gradle build for project:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.2' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm currently working with a Pixelbook which has Linux support (Debian).

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed) help?

Comment: unfortunately, no