# No methods for firebase in build.gradle

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W2Um.png)

Hey guys, I was building a MessengerApp. I would like to connect my App with firebase. The problem is, that there is no dependencies or any methods in build.grade. Can anyone help me? I´m new in this area.

Comment: Most likely you're looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed), right?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is related why there's not buildScript in build.gradle anymore than you can just add it manually, and it will work fine,

```
buildScript{
      dependencies {
           //your required dependencies for build.gradle here
      }
}
```

And if your question is how to integrate firebase in your project, you can check this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcA8OElRc8c&t=153s) to get the understanding.
And for further more on firebase with android, you can check this [Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEl--hArDGE&list=PLQkwcJG4YTCTJLKhPGqgLFTKDsHfF9Arv) out.