# Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found. [ Android ]

Tags: java, android, firebase

## I was Setup firebase

**`Firebase` [Official link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0&hl=en#available-libraries)**
I'm Following This Link my 2nd step went through it correctly, but I think I am doing some mistakes in 3rd & the 4th
There are some flaws in my code that I don't understand,
I will be glad if you can help us.

**build Gradle**:- `Project`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
projects/modules.
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build Gradle**: `Module`

```
plugins {
 id 'com.android.application'
}

//code here..
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
 compileSdk 32

 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.myfire"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
 rules.pro'
    }
 }
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
}

dependencies {
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.0')
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Android Studio?

Comment: @AlexMamo Yes !!

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed) help?

Comment: ( classpath  'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' )                                                          is this line of code necessary?

Comment: Most likely that's the line of code that's missing.

Comment: so will there be any solution

Comment: Add that line your code.

Comment: but still, the error show is happening  : (

Comment: Try to use the exact code in that aswer.

Answer (score 16):

The plugin needs to be referenced in the root `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.14' apply false
}
```

Then it can be applied in a module `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Comment: Very much appreciated. Seems like Google needs to update its docs on this.

Comment: Thank you! saved my day. Indeed google needs to update their docs

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try :

#### Edit

in `build.gradle(Project: AppName)`

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
  }
} // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
  // to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
   id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
   id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

in `build.gradle(Module: AppName)` :

```
plugins {
 id 'com.android.application'
 id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
 // rest code ....
}

dependencies {
 // here your dependencies
}
```

and make sure you have added `google-services.json` to your project.

and I will recommend you to connect firebase by android studio's [firebase tool](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase) and avoid it manually.

Comment: Is it showing up in your `Gradle project file` as well? If not please share your `code`

Comment: @aone yes it is showing

Comment: @aone update answer now you can check