# Android studio gradle sync but non debug

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I made a project, Gradle sync does succeed but when I run ord debug project the Gradle returns errors, I search on the internet but no luck. I'm a beginner in android studio, someone can do the code of Gradle?

build.gradle(project) :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'

    }
}


// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    plugins {

        id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
        id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

build.gradle(module) :

```
plugins {

    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

android {
    compileSdk 32
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.progetto_tpsi"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'


    implementation'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'

    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'

    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.3.1'

    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'


}
```

settins.gradle :

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "progetto_tpsi"
include ':app'
```

**ERROR:**

[image]

> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug

FAILURE: Build completed with 3 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed) out? And try to use `implementation platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0")` along with `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'`?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes i checked and i try to use this implementation but the debug return error. This is first : Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Comment: SOLVED : the dependence of badge cause the error