# Can't add Firebase to Android project

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I can't add the required dependencies to build.gradle because it doesn't look right

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my file but to add irebase dependencies you need a file like this

```
    buildscript {
    
      repositories {
    
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
    
      }
    
      dependencies {
    
        ...
    
        // Add this line
    
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.12'
    
      }
    
    }

allprojects {

  ...

  repositories {

    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):

    google()  // Google's Maven repository

    ...

  }

}
```

why does my build.gradle look wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed)?

Comment: This is not a wrong gradle file. But if you want to change it back to as previous remove the `.kts` extension and replace the code with the second snippet you provided.

Answer (score 0):

In your `build.gradle (project)`. Take note of the google service in the plugins

```
// Paste this buildscript
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // Some other needed classpath 
        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.4.2")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In your `build.gradle (module)`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

    // google service 
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yourAppName"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    // Added newly
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-beta01'

    // firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx:20.0.5'

}
```