# Android studio cannot connect to firebase using the android assistant

Tags: firebase

I  cannot connect my new app to my firebase database.
Previously i have been connecting using the same way,but i have kept on trying to no avail.
what could be the problem?

Comment: Any errors, or other description that might help someone to solve this? Otherwise I doubt anyone can guess what the issue is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If the assistant doesn't work, try to use the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. It seems that the IDE (Android Studio) was not updated. So I check for updates (Settings > Preference > Appearance and Behavior > Updates), then I tried reconnecting again, but now using the console.