# No connection to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to solve this problem for a few hours with different alternatives that I find in Google and nothing, I do not solve the problem.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pe.idat.proyectofinal"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    //gson
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    // picasso
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
```

another..

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
//dependencyResolutionManagement {
//    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
//    repositories {
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
//        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
//    }
//}
rootProject.name = "Foods"
include ':app'
```

I commented that because I was getting this error:

> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Foods'.
> Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

When I comment it out my application runs correctly but when I try to insert something in Firestore, this appears in the console, but the application continues to run.

> W/Firestore: (24.3.1) [WriteStream]: (f440a7b) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
> W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
> I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
> W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
> W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to report request stats: com.google.android.gms.common.security.ProviderInstallerImpl.reportRequestStats [class android.content.Context, long, long]

I was searching in google and I understood that it could be due to this (I did not have it installed) but the problem continues

[image]

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70883309/android-studios-project-gradle-file-changed) will help.

Comment: I still don't solve the problem. :c